# Why does UiPath robot runs in Debug mode on Chrome in a Test Automation project?

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot, uipath-activity

I have created a new project in UiPath Studio Community Edition v.2021.10.4, and created a new 'Test Automation' project. And created the steps to open a browser, go to specified address and type in login/password and click OK button.

The issue is when I try to **run the script** that I created **not debug**, it runs on debug mode in Chrome, and this navbar pops up in Chrome which says : **UiPath Web Automation 21.10 has started debugging this browser.** , and when it ends the browser closes automatically :

[image: Navbar]

What I want is to execute this script normally, not in a debug mode, and the browser stays open, so I can implement the next steps in my developments.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this by changing the input method of the Activity "Use Application/Browser" from **Chromium API** to **Hardware Events**.